# How to determine the percentage of users using a version of iOS?

Tags: ios

This article: http://www.engadget.com/2014/10/07/ios-8-marketshare-stats/

Claims that Apple displays these statistics on the developer portal. How does one find it ? Is it live ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/

also Apple has a page shows https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/ which they keep it upto date and can be termed as more reliable